# Каким образом добавить строки в результат запроса, которых нет в таблице?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица `journal (id, book_id, reserved_at)`. Мне нужно по запросу дат (от и до, дата кратна месяцу) получить список книг, которые были взяты. Книга берется в библиотеке, то есть её нельзя взять на 2-3 дня, что упрощает задачу. Сейчас это делается довольно просто:

```
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(journal.created_at, '%Y-%m') as date, 
  count(*) as count, 
  books.`title` as `book_title`
FROM `journal` 
LEFT JOIN books on books.id = journal.book_id 
WHERE 
  journal.`created_at` >= "2018-08-01" AND
  journal.`created_at` <= "2019-08-01" 
GROUP BY `date`, `book_id` 
ORDER BY `date` asc
```

Но в задаче сказано, что если даже книга не была взята за месяц ни разу (то есть нет записи в таблице `journal` про эту книгу), то все равно нужно вывести, но count в данном случае будет 0. Сейчас это сделано на стороне бэкенда, нужно сделать это на стороне БД. Каким образом это лучше сделать?

Comment: А зачем вы делаете left join таблицы books ? вы ожидаете что в jurnal будут записи, которых нет в books ? Вряд ли. Используйте left join по прямому назначению - выдавать записи основной таблицы (которая слева) даже если нет записей во второй таблице (которая справа). правда все условия на даты потребуется перенести в ON.

Comment: @Mike да, Вы правы. Сюда писал на скорую руку, в проекте не `LEFT JOIN` написал.